# Ajax setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, ajax, timeout

I am using Ajax to submit a form on keyup.

Once the form has been auto submitted a result is shown from the page

```
success: function (response){
$("#search_results<?php echo $HoursID ?>").html(response);
setTimeout(response, 1500);
```

The timeout here isn't working, what have i missed?

Answer (score 3):

The correct usage for `setTimeout()` function is:

```
success: function(response){
  setTimeout(function(){
     $("#search_results<?php echo $HoursID ?>").html(response);
  }, 1500);
}
```

For more info look at:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp